# Select template

Tags: c#, linq, select

Is it possible to make a template for `SELECT` in a `LINQ` query? Right now I have `6` methods that uses the exact same SELECT, i would like to use a template if possible.

This is the code I'm using, when I want to make a change to the select I have to change the same thing at so many places in my code.

```
result = query.Select(b => new
{
    route_id = b.b.route_id,
    name = b.b.name,
    description = b.b.description,
    distance = b.b.distance,
    distance_to_route = (int)b.distance_to_from_me,
    departure_place = b.b.departure_place,
    arrival_place = b.b.arrival_place,
    owner = b.b.user.username,
    average_rating = b.avg_rating,
    is_favorite = b.is_favorite,
    date = b.b.date,
    attributes = b.b.route_attributes.Select(c => 
        c.route_attribute_types.attribute_name),
    coordinates = b.b.coordinates.Select(c => 
        new coordinateToSend { sequence = c.sequence, 
            lat = c.position.Latitude, 
            lon = c.position.Longitude })
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use a class with an appropriate constructor?

Comment: try some mappers like AutoMapper but also with Tim suggestions

Comment: So i can make a class that creates the Select for me?

Comment: Could you show an example please Tim Schmelter

Comment: There are a couple of different ways this can be done, I have given an example of how I would normally create a shared type transformation method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of one way you could do this:

In your example, you're converting the source type to an anonymous type.  You could create a class to represent your converted/result type, for example:

```
    public class ResultClass
    {
        public string ResultPropA { get; set; }
    }
```

For examples sake, lets say the following was the definition of your source class:

```
    public class SourceClass
    {
        public string SourcePropA { get; set; }
    }
```

Now that you have type definitions for your source and result objects, you can create an extension method to convert a collection of your source class to a collection of your result class:

```
    public static class SourceToResultRepository
    {
        public static IEnumerable<ResultClass> ConvertSourceToResult
            (this IEnumerable<SourceClass> source)
        {
            return source.Select(s => new ResultClass
            {
                ResultPropA = s.SourcePropA
                //Add all other property transformations here
            });
        }
    }
```

And here is an example of how you could use it wherever you need to perform the transformation:

```
 //Extension usage:
 var result = Database.Source.ConvertSourceToResult();

 //Direct usage:
 var result = SourceToResultRepository.ConvertSourceToResult(Database.Source);
```